# Understanding Quantum Channel and Choi Jamiolkowski Notation

Tags: quantum-operation

I am given the following
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{{\operatorname{#1}}}$

> Let $|i\rangle$, $1 \leq i \leq \on{dim}\,\mathcal{H_A}, |s\rangle$, $1 \leq s \leq \on{dim}\,\mathcal{H_B}$ be unitary bases. Write $\Lambda = \sum_{i,j,s,t}\Lambda^{\begin{pmatrix}i \\ j\end{pmatrix}}_{ \begin{pmatrix}s \\t \end{pmatrix}}|i\rangle \langle j | \otimes|s\rangle\langle t|$ so $CJ(\Lambda)$ Hermitian implies $\Lambda^{\begin{pmatrix}i \\ j\end{pmatrix}}_{ \begin{pmatrix}s \\t \end{pmatrix}} = \overline{\Lambda}^{\begin{pmatrix}j \\ t\end{pmatrix}}_{ \begin{pmatrix}i \\s \end{pmatrix}}$

I know the following

> > 1. $\Lambda$ is a quantum channel such that $$\Lambda : \on{End}(\mathcal{H_A}) \xrightarrow{} \on{End}(\mathcal{H_B})$$
> >        Where $\on{End}(\mathcal{H_A})$ refers to the endomorphism over Hilbert space A
> >        $$$$
> > 2. $CJ$ refers to the Choi-Jamiolkowki isomorphism which is of the form:
> >        $$CJ: \on{Hom}(\on{End}(\mathcal{H_A}),\on{End}(\mathcal{H_B)}) \rightarrow \on{End}(\mathcal{H_A^*}\otimes\mathcal{H_B})$$ where $\on{Hom}$ refers to homomorphism (I believe)

What does the subscript, superscript notation mean on the $\Lambda$s?

Comment: I'm confused, are the binomial-factor-looking things on the $\Lambda$ a latex misprint? If not, where did you see this notation used? Knowing nothing about the context where you saw this, I have to say that I personally often use a similar kind of notation myself, simply because sometimes using upper and lower indices makes things a bit clearer. If you write eg $\Lambda=\sum \Lambda^{ij}_{st} |i\rangle\!\langle j|\otimes|s\rangle\!\langle t|$, you know that upper indices refer to the first system and lower indices to the second one. I haven't seen it used much in papers though

Comment: I agree with @glS that the notation is presumably just a way to denote the matrix elements. I'd write $\Lambda_{is,jt}$, but there are several ways you could do it. I've never seen this way of doing it. I'd have liked to confirm that by checking the stated Hermitian relation, but I don't understand it. Each of the 4 indices ought to run over the same range. That would mean $(i,j)$ have the same range (top row of the Hermitian relation), as should $(j,t)$, $(s,i)$ and $(t,s)$. So all indices have the same range. But there's supposed to be two distinct ranges.

Comment: It is somewhat a Latex misprint, the binomial factor looking things are supposed to look more like superscripts and subscripts of the $\Lambda$ but still in the binomial factor looking form, just smaller. That makes sense though that it would just be a way of denoting matrix elements. I was confused in that i and s may have completely different dimensions, so then listing them one on top of the other was a little confusing for me.

Comment: @johnsmith Where have you seen this notation?